# Como criar uma tabela dinâmica no Word via Delphi?

Tags: delphi, tabela-html, microsoft-word

Tenho documentos *.doc/*.docx, que estou fazendo a substituição de TAGs, porém agora necessito fazer a criação de uma tabela dinâmica, com base em um select, nestes mesmos arquivos que estou substituindo tags. Essa tabela deve estar abaixo do texto já existente no arquivo.

Já fiz diversas pesquisas, porém não consegui obter sucesso com os exemplos, devido a não estar bem explicado. Alguém poderia dar um exemplo?

Comment: Cara, a única vez que precisei mexer com tabela no Word, eu conseguia inserir linhas, remover e alterar os dados das linhas, mas não consegui cria-la dinamicamente. Então eu tinha um arquivo modelo com uma tabela de uma linha, e ia inserindo as demais linhas conforme a necessidade. Se isso servir pra você, insiro uma resposta mostrando com fiz.

Comment: @RobertoFagundes, já ajuda, dessa forma consigo deixar a tabela em um lugar especifico do arquivo e ir inserindo dados.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existe componentes nativos para isso. Para habilitar vai em:

> Component/Install packages.../ 
>   Microsoft Office XP Sample Automation Server Wrapper Components.

Vai habilitar uma paleta chamada **Servers**. Provavelmente o que você quer é o ***TWordApplication***.

Answer (score 1):

Eu fiz para exportação de um programa, veja se ajuda:

```pascal
procedure TfrmPrincipal.Word1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  WordApp, NewDoc, WordTable : OleVariant;
  i : Integer;
  s : string;
begin
  if RichEdit1.Lines.Count > 1 then
  begin
    WordApp := CreateOleObject('Word.Application');
    WordApp.Visible := True;
    NewDoc := WordApp.Documents.Add;
    WordTable := NewDoc.Tables.Add(WordApp.Selection.Range, 1, 1);
    WordTable.Cell(1,1).Range.Paragraphs.Alignment := wdAlignParagraphcenter;
    WordTable.Cell(1,1).Range.Paragraphs.SpaceAfter := 0;
    WordTable.Borders.OutsideLineStyle := wdLineStyleSingle;
    s := '';
    for i := 1 to RichEdit1.Lines.Count-1 do
    begin
      s := s + RichEdit1.Lines.Strings[i]+#13+#10;
    end;
    s := Copy(s,1,Length(s)-2);
    WordApp.Selection.Font.Size := 8;
    WordApp.Selection.Font.Name := 'Courier New';

    WordTable.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text := s;
    // Cleanup...
    WordApp := Unassigned;
    NewDoc := Unassigned;
    WordTable := Unassigned;
  end;
end;
```